# \listoffigures and \listoftables not populated

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm doing a long book with lots of figures and a few tables. I've put the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` tags in just after the `\begin{document}` tag but when I compile I get only the "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" titles and nothing listed. My header file has a lot of packages listed in it so I thought perhaps one of them might be causing the problem. So, I did a test with a short one-figure chapter in it and using the same header file so that I could eliminate packages until I found the offending one. To my surprise, it worked ... the packages that I'm using are not interfering. So, what might be the cause of the problem?

Here's the header file:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[draft,12pt]{book}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% packages used
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[arrowdel]{physics}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsbsy,textcomp}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{showframe}

% aliases, new commands and macros here
%\newcommand\textsubscript[1]{\ensuremath{{}_{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}
\newcommand\boldsubformula[1]{\text{\mathversion{bold}$#1$}}
\newcommand{\mop}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{\hat #1}}}            %mop - matrix operator
\newcommand{\tens}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{\overset{\sim} #1}}} %tens - tensor
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\title{Essential Mathematics\\for NMR Spectroscopists}
\author{K.C. Brown\\Department of Chemistry\\University of Saskatchewan}
\date{\today\\[3pt]
Copyright \copyright\ K.C. Brown 2015}

\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\makeindex
\geometry{top=0.75in,left=0.80in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

and here's the master file:

```
\include{header}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\include{preface}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\fontsize{12}{14}
%========================================[Complex Numbers]========================================
\include{ComplexNumbers}

%=========================================[Matrices]==============================================
\include{Matrices}
```

etc.

Comment: Can you show one of the `figure` environments you have? By the way, remove `\everymath{\displaystyle}` which is utterly wrong and  `\fontsize{12}{14}` that does nothing. Also `\include{header}` should by `\input{header}`.

Comment: Thanks egreg. I'm still very much a noob at Latex but learning more all the time. Here's an example figure:\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics{Complex1}
\caption{The Argand diagram.}
\label{fig:Argand}
\end{figure}

Comment: The lists of figures and tables are populated on the *second* LaTeX run, provided you don't remove auxiliary files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter how many runs I do .. no list of figures or tables, just the list titles. :(